# Insert Select from other table with same id

Tags: mysql

here is my table1

```
 id  | userid | country

  1  | 25     |    
  2  | 36     |    
  3  | 24     |  
  4  | 24     |   
  5  | 25     |  
  6  | 24     |
```

table2

```
  id   |  country

  25   |   Algeria  
  36   |   Canada
  24   |   Sweden
  15   |   China
```

> WHERE table2.id = table1.userid

so my result will be

```
  id  | userid | country

  1  | 25     |  Algeria 
  2  | 36     |  Canada 
  3  | 24     |  Sweden
  4  | 24     |  Sweden 
  5  | 25     |  Algeria
  6  | 24     |  Sweden
```

[my SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f7bf/1).

i have tried this

```
 INSERT INTO `table1`(`country`) 
  SELECT m.country from table2 m , table1 v WHERE  m.id = v.userid
```

but it inserts nothing.  i wonder where  the error  is? .

EDIT.

country field is Empty its just the fidle showed null values

Comment: You know it's an INT, right?

Comment: be careful when using `SQLFiddle`'s `Text to DDL`. The default data type is `int` if you have column which all values are `NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be doing `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` because row already exist and you want to modify certain field.

```
UPDATE  table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.userid = b.id
SET     a.country = b.country
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af737/1)

Comment: why update ? its empty field. its new created and its empty , in fiddle its just showed null wait i update

Comment: because you are modifying, not adding new one.

Comment: you are right i missed it. i thought i will insert to the new column what stupid thinking hahaha , thanks it worked :)